# TeamCity: Manual Approval

Tags: jenkins, teamcity

I am trying to set up a manual approval build configuration in my TeamCity Build Chain. Something like an email or any form of notification to my QA to approve or reject the promotion.

I've been searching the web for 2 days now but to no avail which leads me to believe that it doesn't have the feature. Can someone please give me some tips or tricks to achieve this.

Comment: I am facing the same issue with Teamcity. It doesn't support manual approvals. We added a check from Jira status for approvals, in a scheduled manner. But, its just temporary. Looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a "Build Approval" Feature in Teamcity

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/cloud/build-approval.html

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I found this [support request](https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203391604-Approve-Workflow).

> Currently there us no special support in TeamCity for this case. We have the related request in our tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-26623, please vote for it.
>
> In TeamCity team we use tags to approve that changes are safe for deployment. For more details please see the blog post: https://blog.jetbrains.com/team/2015/10/08/how-teamcity-uses-teamcity/.

The ticket has been sitting in the backlog for quite some time, but recently someone came up and at least did some design on it so there is some hope it will get moving.